# How to launch Seamonkey?

Tags: release-loki

I want to use Seamonkey, that normally is simply to be run with `./seamonkey` or dropping the executable in a terminal, etc.

But I get this wrror:

```
./seamonkey
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/cipeos/programs/seamonkey (2)/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

That file is set to be executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the `libdbus-glib-1-2` error, make sure it's [up to date](http://el.web.id/how-to-solve-xpcomglueload-error-couldnt-load-xpcom-mozilla-firefox-debian-149):

```
sudo apt install libdbus-glib-1-2
```

The issue is more likely (in 2016) that Seamonkey gave you the wrong installer. The 64-bit version is [hidden at the bottom of the download page](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/releases/#contrib). Be sure to use that x86_64 tar if you are using a 64-bit operating system (like Loki).

[image: download page]

Alternatively, use [the Ubuntuzilla repo install method](https://askubuntu.com/a/397654/49899) or [the deb files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/s/seamonkey-mozilla-build/).

Comment: `libdbus-glib-1-2 is already the newest version (0.106-1).
`

Comment: I have even tried to replicate the entire situation from the linked page: the same error.

Comment: @cipricus, did you install with the website's main tar file or did you use the PPA? Are you on a 64-bit system, and if so, did you use [the 64-bit installer](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/releases/#contrib)? (It's kind of hidden away)

Comment: I have downloaded the main package for Linux which is the only one available on their main site: http://www.seamonkey-project.org/releases/#2.40, which I had used in the past by extracting and running `seamonkey` file (I am used to create a desktop launcher for that, etc). -- I am not aware of a PPA, but just a few minutes ago I have found the deb file I needed and that works. I shall post that as solution I guess. Thanks for your responsiveness.

Comment: I see what you mean!! It's a 64x version posted separately! That is a bit stupid I guess. You were right all along!!!

Comment: I have added your comments inside the answer.